# df shows that no space left, but du disagree

Tags: disk-usage, deleted-files

`df -h` show that I'm almost out of space on my `/` (output is truncated):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3,2G  2,2M  3,2G   1% /run
/dev/sda5        64G   60G  874M  99% /
```

But `du -sch /` says that it takes only `36G` out of `64G`.

What I did:

1. Checked deleted, but still opened files with `lsof | grep deleted`. I did that from recovery mode and it shows empty output. But space is still taken
2. Checked percentage of space reserved for `root`. It was 20, changed to 5. But nothing changed

Would be really glad to hear any ideas what can be a reason for that! Thank you

Comment: run fsck or format disk

Comment: I assume that you have rebooted to take care of any open but deleted files. Very unlikely but do you have a large number of small files so that inodes are taking up disk space?

Comment: Does `du -h --apparent-size`  change anything in this? Are you having sparse files somewhere? The outputs might be deceiving. Also I think this is quite a nice read: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-numbers-du-s-and-df-disagree

Comment: You might have ran out of inodes. Can you try this ```df -i``` so we can see the current inode usage?

Comment: Is this a physical machine or a VM? Is Docker involved? What filesystem is `/` using? Did you run the `df -h /` from recovery mode too? If not please could you run it and the `du` again, in the same recovery session

Comment: @doneal24 seems inodes are OK, only 12% used

Comment: @ValentinBajrami that is very strange but with `--apparent-size` du shows 130Tb space used, but w/o - 1.4Tb (and that is definitely much more real). Can that be the source of my problem?